# Configuration.save() doesn't work when called from different server

Tags: c#, networking, cmd

I have an EXE on my web server to modify XML (a web.config `appSettings` value). If I call the EXE on the server in CMD window it works. However, if I execute the EXE from a different server on the network, `Configuration.save()` has no affect. I have done logging and confirmed in both cases it walks through the code just the same, but `Configuration.save()` simply has no affect when called from this other server. It doesn't return an error, I can't find any trace of an error. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: If server A calls an EXE on server B....it executes on server A?

Comment: I used PsExec to solve.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx